# How to sum the values of one colum except negative numbers or null in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT SUM(PQ.QuotaValue)
FROM PackageQuotas AS PQ
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT PackageID,
                    ParentPackageID
    FROM Packages
    WHERE ParentPackageID = @ParentPackageID
) PA ON PQ.PackageID = PA.PackageID
WHERE PQ.QuotaID = @QuotaID
```

The common column is the ParentPackageID of table Packages with the PackageId from PackageQuotas.

The problem is how to avoid adding negative numbers of column `PackageQuotas`

Can this query become simpler ?

Comment: `WHERE PQ.QuotaValue > 0` ?

Comment: Ok.let me try it,but can you make it simpler the whole query ?

Comment: It can't be any simplier than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE /* UNIQUE */ INDEX ix ON dbo.PackageQuotas (QuotaID, PackageID)
    INCLUDE (QuotaValue)
    WHERE QuotaValue > 0

SELECT SUM(q.QuotaValue)
FROM dbo.PackageQuotas q /* WITH(INDEX(ix)) */
WHERE q.QuotaID = @QuotaID
    AND q.QuotaValue > 0
    AND EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.Packages p
            WHERE p.ParentPackageID = @ParentPackageID
                AND q.PackageID = p.PackageID
        )
```

My post about `0` and `NULL` inside `SUM`, `AVG` - http://blog.devart.com/what-is-faster-inside-stream-aggregate-hash-match.html

Comment: as I am learning, why is this better than the initial script?just to know

Comment: Why better? Unnecessary `DISTINCT` which causes `Sort Distinct` operation. Just check your execution plan. In additional, filtered index may improve your perfomance

Comment: @Giannis Grivas you are welcome ;) and check my post if you want to know more about `sql-server` :)

Comment: And the last one is that I want if the result is null to make it zero , how is this possible?

Comment: `ISNULL(SUM(...), 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the null and Negative values by adding condition in Where Clause

```
 SELECT SUM(PQ.QuotaValue)
    FROM PackageQuotas AS PQ
    JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT PackageID,
                        ParentPackageID
        FROM Packages
        WHERE ParentPackageID = @ParentPackageID
    ) PA ON PQ.PackageID = PA.PackageID
    WHERE PQ.QuotaID = @QuotaID AND PQ.QuotaValue IS NOT NULL AND PQ.QuotaValue > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `CASE` in `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN PQ.QuotaValue > 0 THEN PQ.QuotaValue ELSE 0 END)
FROM PackageQuotas AS PQ
JOIN (
 SELECT DISTINCT PackageID,
                ParentPackageID
 FROM Packages
 WHERE ParentPackageID = @ParentPackageID
) PA ON PQ.PackageID = PA.PackageID
WHERE PQ.QuotaID = @QuotaID
```